# SQL select based on column value unpivot/pivot column based to row based

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, case, col

I have found a lot of similar case but not than, let me explain ,

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

D column values are target ID and other GRC columns are all the target with their values (I just putted dummy values)

The table is a bit tricky because it looks like a pivot table, I try to unpivot it but no success.
There is more than 200 target columns so the idea is to select only target columns which are in col D. 
I achieved that with an IN BUT it a new target is use then I have to change it so not dynamic at all.

My question is it possible to select "col" from where col are the col in D like a select distinct value from col D en then select where in D

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  A  |  B  |  C  |   D   |     Date   |  GRC03  |    GRC06 | GRC08  | GRC21 | GRC25 |    GRC29    |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------------+
| XXX | yyy | zzz | GRC03 | 01/01/2020 |     567 |       89 |     65 |     1 |    87 |          23 |
| Xxx | yyy | zzz | GRC06 | 01/01/2020 |     989 |       76 |     43 |     2 |    56 |          24 |
| XXX | yyy | zzz | GRC08 | 02/01/2020 |      67 |       54 |     21 |     3 |    67 |          89 |
| XXX | yyy | zzz | GRC03 | 02/01/2020 |      41 |       38 |     -1 |     4 |    50 | 111,3333333 |
| Xxx | yyy | zzz | GRC06 | 02/01/2020 |    -209 |     20,5 |    -23 |     5 |    40 | 144,3333333 |
| XXX | yyy | zzz | GRC08 | 03/01/2020 |    -459 |        3 |    -45 |     6 |    30 | 177,3333333 |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+------------+---------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Result I would like

```
+------------+-------+-------------+
|    DATE    |    D  |   RESULTS   |
+------------+-------+-------------+
| 01/01/2020 | GRC03 |         567 |
| 01/01/2020 | GRC06 |          89 |
| 02/01/2020 | GRC08 |          21 |
| 02/01/2020 | GRC21 |           4 |
| 02/01/2020 | GRC25 |          67 |
| 03/01/2020 | GRC29 | 177,3333333 |
+------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve] is great reading, to get better answers!

Comment: Okay thx I will do that :) How may I send you an example? Not copy paste I guess, sorry I am not often here :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
select d, date,
       (case when d = 'GRC03' then GRC03
             when d = 'GRC06' then GRC06
             when d = 'GRC08' then GRC08
             when d = 'GRC21' then GRC21
             when d = 'GRC25' then GRC25
             when d = 'GRC29' then GRC29
        end) as results
from t;
```

You can also unpivot using `apply` and filter:

```
select t.d, t.date, v.val
from t cross apply
     (values ('GRC03', GRC03),
             ('GRC06', GRC06),
             ('GRC08', GRC08),
             ('GRC21', GRC21),
             ('GRC25', GRC25),
             ('GRC29', GRC29)
     ) v(col, val)
where v.col = d;
```

Comment: Thx! I have more than 200 columns but yes it works , thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can try UNPIVOT operator as given in the below sample code.

[UNPIVOT AND PIVOT BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT Date,D, Results
FROM
(SELECT Date, GRC03, GRC06, GRC08...
FROM YourTable
)
UNPIVOT
(
D FOR Results IN (GRC03, GRC06, GRC08...)
) AS GRCReslts
```

Comment: Thx! Sorry but didn't catch everything: first select, the results column is the one I want as the unpivot table, correct? then in the second select the GRC colunms are the column from my original table, right? then UNPIVOT d for results in ( here = value in D then , ? Am I right ?